# How do I keep and separate the data that is unique to each method, in all three methods, or in just two methods?

Tags: r, duplicates, subset, unique

I have a data set where I have identified compounds from each different experimental method (Gradient, Isocratic, and HILIC). I would like to be able to store/subset results such that I get the compounds that are identified in all three methods, unique to each method, and the overlap between two methods. Eventually I would be able to create a Venn Diagram type figure between the three methods and the identified compounds.

I have tried "unique()" and "subset()" on the column "Compound", but I don't know how to add another condition for the method.

```
'''head(Data, n = 12)'''
       Precursor.Ion         Compound    Method
1            141             Methanol  Gradient
2            143             Methanol  Gradient
3             82              Toluene  Gradient
4             54          Isopropanol  Gradient
5             47                Water  Gradient
6             45                Water  Gradient
7            135              Toluene Isocratic
8             82          Acetonirile Isocratic
9             91              Acetone Isocratic
10            43              Toluene     HILIC
11            31          Isopropanol     HILIC
12            97 Methyltertbutylether     HILIC

'''unique(Data$Compound)'''
Methanol             Toluene              Isopropanol          Water               
Acetonirile          Acetone              Methyltertbutylether
```

I would expect the output to be something like this stored in the following variables

```
'''All'''
Toluene
'''Gradient'''
Methanol   Water
'''Isocratic'''
Acetone, Acetonitrile
'''HILIC'''
Methyltertbutylether
'''Gradient and Isocratic'''
N/A
'''Gradient and HILIC'''
Isopropanol
'''Isocratic and HILIC'''
N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively simple Tidyverse approach that unfortunately misses the `N/A` entries.  If you really need those, they can be added afterwards.  (Additionally, `Gradient, Isocratic, HILIC` corresponds to `All`.)

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(readr)
> tbl <- read_table("
+       141             Methanol  Gradient
+       143             Methanol  Gradient
+        82              Toluene  Gradient
+        54          Isopropanol  Gradient
+        47                Water  Gradient
+        45                Water  Gradient
+       135              Toluene Isocratic
+        82          Acetonirile Isocratic
+        91              Acetone Isocratic
+        43              Toluene     HILIC
+        31          Isopropanol     HILIC
+        97 Methyltertbutylether     HILIC
+ ",
+ col_names=c("Precursor.Ion", "Compound", "Method"),
+ col_types=cols(Precursor.Ion=col_integer(), Compound=col_character(), Method=col_character()))
> collapse <- ", "
> tbl %>%
+     group_by(Compound) %>%
+     summarize(Methods=sort(paste(unique(Method), collapse=collapse))) %>%
+     group_by(Methods) %>%
+     summarize(Compounds=sort(paste(unique(Compound), collapse=collapse)))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Methods                    Compounds           
  <chr>                      <chr>               
1 Gradient                   Methanol, Water     
2 Gradient, HILIC            Isopropanol         
3 Gradient, Isocratic, HILIC Toluene             
4 HILIC                      Methyltertbutylether
5 Isocratic                  Acetone, Acetonirile
```

Comment: Hi d125q. Thank you for your help. The N/A's are fine if they don't come up! Is there a way to supply it with a data frame instead of a tbl? Would I need to use grouped_df instead of group_by?

Comment: You can use a data frame instead of a tibble without any problems.

Comment: I keep getting this error, "Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor""

Comment: I have already reclassified each column as type character as you had above. The code is as follows: Data %>%
  +     group_by(Compound) %>%
  +     summarize(Method=sort(paste(unique(Method), collapse=collapse))) %>%
  +     grouped_by(Method) %>%
  +     summarize(Compound=sort(paste(unique(Compound), collapse=collapse)))

Answer (score 0):

This would be very easy with my `nVennR` package. With the table stored in `myT`,

```
> library(nVennR)
> grad <- subset(myT, Method == "Gradient")$Compound
> iso <- subset(myT, Method == "Isocratic")$Compound
> hil <- subset(myT, Method == "HILIC")$Compound
> myV <- plotVenn(list(Gradient=grad, Isocratic=iso, HILIC=hil))

> listVennRegions(myV)
$`0, 0, 1 (HILIC)`
[1] "Methyltertbutylether"

$`0, 1, 0 (Isocratic)`
[1] "Acetonirile" "Acetone"    

$`1, 0, 0 (Gradient)`
[1] "Methanol" "Water"   

$`1, 0, 1 (Gradient, HILIC)`
[1] "Isopropanol"

$`1, 1, 1 (Gradient, Isocratic, HILIC)`
[1] "Toluene"


> listVennRegions(myV, na.rm = F)
$`0, 0, 0 ()`
[1] NA

$`0, 0, 1 (HILIC)`
[1] "Methyltertbutylether"

$`0, 1, 0 (Isocratic)`
[1] "Acetonirile" "Acetone"    

$`0, 1, 1 (Isocratic, HILIC)`
[1] NA

$`1, 0, 0 (Gradient)`
[1] "Methanol" "Water"   

$`1, 0, 1 (Gradient, HILIC)`
[1] "Isopropanol"

$`1, 1, 0 (Gradient, Isocratic)`
[1] NA

$`1, 1, 1 (Gradient, Isocratic, HILIC)`
[1] "Toluene"
```

You also get a Venn diagram:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect vqf. I'm having an error with the venn diagram plot though. Have you seen this error before?Warning message:
In showSVG(myVenn, ...) :
  The figure cannot be rendered in the plot window. Please, use the arguments outFile and/or systemShow.

Comment: Yes, it means that your system does not have a recognized way to plot the venn diagram. You would need the `rsvg` and `grImport2` packages for that, plus a plot window (for instance, you cannot plot directly in a command-line environment). The command suggests that you can export the svg figure directly by writing `myV <- plotVenn(list(Gradient=grad, Isocratic=iso, HILIC=hil), outFile=path_to_exported_picture)`.